# swift 3: connect to database using json format

Tags: json, swift3

I want to POST a JSON  web request to the webserver through an `ios` application when I press on a button.

Now, there is a field in the database of the webserver, and the field is initialised with the value `false`. When the button is pressed in the app (meaning: when the POST request reaches the webserver), I have to change that fields value into `true`.

Can you please give me a code or a video that can help me to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: Made it clearer that the asker wants to change a DB field value when a POST request reaches the webserver. Added paragraphs and made certain acronyms uppercase.